# WordPress Promotion slider Plugin : "Set Featured Image" link is not showing in Screen options

Tags: wordpress

I have added the below line of code in the theme folder **/wp-content/themes/brave-zeenat/function.php** file as recommended by [WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

But still "Set Featured image" option is not showing in Screen options page.need your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the featured image checkbox is ticked under "Screen Options". You can find this dropdown at the top of the page.

Comment: Have you tried:


- deactivating all plugins to see if this resolves the problem? If this works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the problematic plugin(s).


- switching to the Twenty Ten theme to rule out any theme-specific problems?


- resetting the plugins folder by FTP or phpMyAdmin? Sometimes, an apparently inactive plugin can still cause problems.


- re-uploading the wp-admin and wp-includes folders from a fresh download of WordPress?


- increasing the memory available to PHP?
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/253495#post-1017842